# Generic Type Specification for Class Object

Tags: java, generics

I'm using a HashMap and the method show below to track change listeners for class types. The IDE is giving a warning

```
[rawtypes] found raw type: java.lang.Class
  missing type parameters for generic class java.lang.Class<T>.
```

What type for Class needs to be specified to resolve the warning?

```
private HashMap<Class, Set<ChangeListener>> classChangeListeners;

/**
 * Adds a ChangeListener to the listener list for the specified class type. The class type
 * specified must be a subclass of {@link BusinessObject}.
 *
 * @param  <T>  the type of BusinessObject.
 * @param  cls  the class type.
 * @param  listener  the ChangeListener to be added.
 */
public <T extends BusinessObject> void addChangeListener(Class<T> cls, ChangeListener listener)
{
 if (!classChangeListeners.containsKey(cls))
 {
  classChangeListeners.put(cls, new TreeSet<ChangeListener>());
 }

 classChangeListeners.get(cls).add(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care to specify the type of the particular `Class`es you are working with, you can use `Class<?>` instead of the [raw type](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html) `Class`.

In some cases you'd want to wildcard it, `Class<? extends BusinessObject>` or parametrize it, `Class<T>` - but usually `Class<?>` will be sufficient, and it's hard to infer what you actually want from a short snippet.

Also, it looks like you're using a Map containing Sets.  You could look into using a [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) which has this functionality built in and makes it a lot nicer to work with.

Comment: From the looks of your code, apparently Class<? extends BusinessObject> would be most appropriate.

Comment: As long as the invariant documented on the method actually holds for the Map itself (where it's not documented explicitly), I'd agree...

Comment: I suppose it depends on what a ChangeListener can handle.  If it can only handle BusinessObjects, then I would go with Carl's suggestion.  If it doesn't matter, I would write Class<?>.  (In general, I prefer <Object> rather than <?> in a data structure because it makes it clear that we're working within a type hierarchy, but Class<Object> means something specific that we don't want.)